# Negation of a Relational Operator

Tags: definition

I read in a paper a definition like this:

Given $\Sigma=\{\neq,=, >,<,\leq,\geq \}$, we define a constraint $v\ op \ w$ with $v,w \in \mathbb{R}$ and $op \in \Sigma$. Moreover, we indicate by $\neg (v\ op \ w)$ the constraint in which $op$ is replaced by its negation.

(I have synthesized the definition)

Now, the question is:  is well-defined to say a negation of a relational operator?

Comment: Well it clearly is in that particular case. The negation of $=$ is $\ne$; the negation of $>$ is $\le$ and the negation of $<$ is $\ge$.